# Control the max number of divs on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I programmed this countdown. How can I control the max number of divs displaying on the page. Example: Thare are 20 countdowns on the page but only 5 are displaying(visible) to user.

> EDIT: Now there are 19 countdown displaying on page, how can I set
>   that thare are max 7 countdown displaying on page?

Here is the code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tramvaj.info</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favi.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    <style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-image: url("bg.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        background-attachment: fixed;       
    }

            #header_container { background:#1f62a7; border:0px solid #1f62a7; height:35px; left:0; position:relative; width:100%; top:0; }


            #headermenu {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:relative;
        top:-8px;
        background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    }
    .headermenu {
        width: 150px;
        height: 26px;
        padding-top:15px;
        display: block;
        float: left;

        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none!important;
        text-transform: uppercase;

        font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 15px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        color: #ffffff!important;

        transition: all .5s ease;
    }

    #page-wrap { width: 230px; margin: 50px auto; padding: 20px; background: white; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; }
            p { font: 30px/2 Georgia, Serif; margin: 0 0 30px 0; text-indent: 40px; }

    a { color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
      } 

    #dani1Box, #sati1Box, #minute1Box, #sekunde1Box, #dani2Box, #sati2Box, #minute2Box, #sekunde2Box, #dani3Box, #sati3Box, #minute3Box, #sekunde3Box, #dani4Box, #sati4Box, #minute4Box, #sekunde4Box, 
    #dani5Box, #sati5Box, #minute5Box, #sekunde5Box, #dani6Box, #sati6Box, #minute6Box, #sekunde6Box, #dani7Box, #sati7Box, #minute7Box, #sekunde7Box, #dani8Box, #sati8Box, #minute8Box, #sekunde8Box,
    #dani9Box, #sati9Box, #minute9Box, #sekunde9Box, #dani10Box, #sati10Box, #minute10Box, #sekunde10Box, #dani11Box, #sati11Box, #minute11Box, #sekunde11Box, #dani12Box, #sati12Box, #minute12Box, #sekunde12Box, #dani1Box, #sati13Box, #minute13Box, #sekunde13Box, #dani14Box, #sati14Box, #minute14Box, #sekunde14Box, #dani15Box, #sati15Box, #minute15Box, #sekunde15Box, #dani16Box, #sati16Box, #minute16Box, #sekunde16Box, #dani17Box, #sati17Box, #minute17Box, #sekunde17Box, #dani18Box, #sati18Box, #minute18Box, #sekunde18Box, #dani19Box, #sati19Box, #minute19Box, #sekunde19Box, #dani20Box, #sati20Box, #minute20Box, #sekunde20Box{
             font-size:25px;
             color:#1f62a7;
             font-family:Sans-serif;
             display: inline-block;
    }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="header_container">
        <div id="header"></div> 
    <div align="center">
    <div id="headermenu">
    <a href="stanice.html" class="headermenu">SVE STANICE</a>
    <a href="about.html" class="headermenu">HOME</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="page-wrap">

    <script>
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    //if(n == 1 || n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 4 || n == 5){
    var timer1;
    function cdtd1() {
        var sad1 = new Date();
        var dolazak1 = new Date(sad1.getFullYear(),sad1.getMonth(),sad1.getDate(),18,00,00);
        var timeDiff1 = dolazak1.getTime() - sad1.getTime();
        if (timeDiff1 <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer1);
            $("#Box1").remove();

        }
        var sekunde1 = Math.floor(timeDiff1 / 1000);
        var minute1 = Math.floor(sekunde1 / 60);
        var sati1 = Math.floor(minute1 / 60);
        var dani1 = Math.floor(sati1 / 24);
        sati1 %= 24;
        minute1 %= 60;
        sekunde1 %= 60;

        $("#dani1Box").html(dani1);
        $("#sati1Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati1 + ':');
        $("#minute1Box").html(minute1 + ':');
        $("#sekunde1Box").html(sekunde1);

        timer1 = setTimeout(cdtd1, 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
         cdtd1();
    });
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    var timer2;
    function cdtd2() {
        var sad2 = n

        ew Date();
            var dolazak2 = new Date(sad2.getFullYear(),sad2.getMonth(),sad2.getDate(),18,00,00);
            var timeDiff2 = dolazak2.getTime() - sad2.getTime();
            if (timeDiff2 <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer2);
                $("#Box2").remove();

            }
            var sekunde2 = Math.floor(timeDiff2 / 1000);
            var minute2 = Math.floor(sekunde2 / 60);
            var sati2 = Math.floor(minute2 / 60);
            var dani2 = Math.floor(sati2 / 24);
            sati2 %= 24;
            minute2 %= 60;
            sekunde2 %= 60;
            $("#dani2Box").html(dani2);
            $("#sati2Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati2 + ':');
            $("#minute2Box").html(minute2 + ':');
            $("#sekunde2Box").html(sekunde2);

            timer2 = setTimeout(cdtd2, 1000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
             cdtd2();
        });
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var timer3;
        function cdtd3() {
            var sad3 = new Date();
            var dolazak3 = new Date(sad3.getFullYear(),sad3.getMonth(),sad3.getDate(),18,00,00);
            var timeDiff3 = dolazak3.getTime() - sad3.getTime();
            if (timeDiff3 <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer3);
                $("#Box3").remove();


            }
            var sekunde3 = Math.floor(timeDiff3 / 1000);
            var minute3 = Math.floor(sekunde3 / 60);
            var sati3 = Math.floor(minute3 / 60);
            var dani3 = Math.floor(sati3 / 24);
            sati3 %= 24;
            minute3 %= 60;
            sekunde3 %= 60;

            $("#dani3Box").html(dani3);
            $("#sati3Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati3 + ':');
            $("#minute3Box").html(minute3 + ':');
            $("#sekunde3Box").html(sekunde3);

            timer3 = setTimeout(cdtd3, 1000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
             cdtd3();
        });
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        var timer4;
        function cdtd4() {
            var sad4 = new Date();
            var dolazak4 = new Date(sad4.getFullYear(),sad4.getMonth(),sad4.getDate(),18,00,00);
            var timeDiff4 = dolazak4.getTime() - sad4.getTime();
            if (timeDiff4 <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer4);
                $("#Box4").remove();


            }
            var sekunde4 = Math.floor(timeDiff4 / 1000);
            var minute4 = Math.floor(sekunde4 / 60);
            var sati4 = Math.floor(minute4 / 60);
            var dani4 = Math.floor(sati4 / 24);
            sati4 %= 24;
            minute4 %= 60;
            sekunde4 %= 60;

            $("#dani4Box").html(dani4);
            $("#sati4Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati4 + ':');
            $("#minute4Box").html(minute4 + ':');
            $("#sekunde4Box").html(sekunde4);

            timer4 = setTimeout(cdtd4, 1000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
             cdtd4();
        });

        var timer5;
        function cdtd5() {
            var sad5 = new Date();
            var dolazak5 = new Date(sad5.getFullYear(),sad5.getMonth(),sad5.getDate(),18,00,00);
            var timeDiff5 = dolazak5.getTime() - sad5.getTime();
            if (timeDiff5 <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer5);
                $("#Box5").remove();


            }
            var sekunde5 = Math.floor(timeDiff5 / 1000);
            var minute5 = Math.floor(sekunde5 / 60);
            var sati5 = Math.floor(minute5 / 60);
            var dani5 = Math.floor(sati5 / 24);
            sati5 %= 24;
            minute5 %= 60;
            sekunde5 %= 60;

            $("#dani5Box").html(dani5);
            $("#sati5Box").html('14-Zapruđe ' + sati5 + ':');
            $("#minute5Box").html(minute5 + ':');
            $("#sekunde5Box").html(sekunde5);







     timer5 = setTimeout(cdtd5, 1000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
             cdtd5();
        });


        var timer6;
        function cdtd6() {
            var sad6 = new Date();
            var dolazak6 = new Date(sad6.getFullYear(),sad6.getMonth(),sad6.getDate(),18,00,00);
            var timeDiff6 = dolazak6.getTime() - sad6.getTime();
            if (timeDiff6 <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer6);
                $("#Box6")

    .remove();


        }
        var sekunde6 = Math.floor(timeDiff6 / 1000);
        var minute6 = Math.floor(sekunde6 / 60);
        var sati6 = Math.floor(minute6 / 60);
        var dani6 = Math.floor(sati6 / 24);
        sati6 %= 24;
        minute6 %= 60;
        sekunde6 %= 60;

        $("#dani6Box").html(dani6);
        $("#sati6Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati6 + ':');
        $("#minute6Box").html(minute6 + ':');
        $("#sekunde6Box").html(sekunde6);

        timer6 = setTimeout(cdtd6, 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
         cdtd6();
    });

    var timer7;
    function cdtd7() {
        var sad7 = new Date();
        var dolazak7 = new Date(sad7.getFullYear(),sad7.getMonth(),sad7.getDate(),18,00,00);
        var timeDiff7 = dolazak7.getTime() - sad7.getTime();
        if (timeDiff7 <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer7);
            $("#Box7").remove();


        }
        var sekunde7 = Math.floor(timeDiff7 / 1000);
        var minute7 = Math.floor(sekunde7/ 60);
        var sati7 = Math.floor(minute7 / 60);
        var dani7 = Math.floor(sati7 / 24);
        sati7 %= 24;
        minute7 %= 60;
        sekunde7 %= 60;

        $("#dani7Box").html(dani7);
        $("#sati7Box").html('14-Zapruđe ' + sati7 + ':');
        $("#minute7Box").html(minute7 + ':');
        $("#sekunde7Box").html(sekunde7);



        timer7 = setTimeout(cdtd7, 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
         cdtd7();
    });


    var timer8;
    function cdtd8() {
        var sad8 = new Date();
        var dolazak8 = new Date(sad8.getFullYear(),sad8.getMonth(),sad8.getDate(),18,00,00);
        var timeDiff8 = dolazak8.getTime() - sad8.getTime();
        if (timeDiff8 <= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer8);
            $("#Box8").remove();


        }
        var sekunde8 = Math.floor(timeDiff8 / 1000);
        var minute8 = Math.floor(sekunde8 / 60);
        var sati8 = Math.floor(minute8 / 60);
        var dani8 = Math.floor(sati8 / 24);
        sati8 %= 24;
        minute8 %= 60;
        sekunde8 %= 60;

        $("#dani8Box").html(dani8);
        $("#sati8Box").html('14-Zapruđe ' + sati8 + ':');
        $("#minute8Box").html(minute8 + ':');
        $("#sekunde8Box").html(sekunde8);

        timer8 = setTimeout(cdtd8, 1000);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
         cdtd8();
    });

var timer9;
function cdtd9() {
    var sad9 = new Date();
    var dolazak9 = new Date(sad9.getFullYear(),sad9.getMonth(),sad9.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff9= dolazak9.getTime() - sad9.getTime();
    if (timeDiff9 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer9);
        $("#Box9").remove();


    }
    var sekunde9 = Math.floor(timeDiff9/ 1000);
    var minute9 = Math.floor(sekunde9/ 60);
    var sati9= Math.floor(minute9 / 60);
    var dani9= Math.floor(sati9/ 24);
    sati9 %= 24;
    minute9 %= 60;
    sekunde9 %= 60;

    $("#dani9Box").html(dani9);
    $("#sati9Box").html('14-Zapruđe ' + sati9 + ':');
    $("#minute9Box").html(minute9 + ':');
    $("#sekunde9Box").html(sekunde9);

    timer9 = setTimeout(cdtd9, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd9();
});

var timer10;
function cdtd10() {
    var sad10 = new Date();
    var dolazak10 = new Date(sad10.getFullYear(),sad10.getMonth(),sad10.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff10 = dolazak10.getTime() - sad10.getTime();
    if (timeDiff10 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer10);
        $("#Box10").remove();


    }
    var sekunde10 = Math.floor(timeDiff10/ 1000);
    var minute10 = Math.floor(sekunde10 / 60);
    var sati10 = Math.floor(minute10 / 60);
    var dani10 = Math.floor(sati10/ 24);
    sati10 %= 24;
    minute10 %= 60;
    sekunde10 %= 60;

    $("#dani10Box").html(dani10);
    $("#sati10Box").html('14-Zapruđe ' + sati10 + ':');
    $("#minute10Box").html(minute10 + ':');
    $("#sekunde10Box").html(sekunde10);

    timer10 = setTimeout(cdtd10, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd10();
});

var timer11;
function cdtd11() {
    var sad11 = new Date();
    var dolazak11 = new Date(sad11.getFullYear(),sad11.getMonth(),sad11.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff11 = dolazak11.getTime() - sad11.getTime();
    if (timeDiff11 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer11);
        $("#Box11").remove();

    }
    var sekunde11 = Math.floor(timeDiff11 / 1000);
    var minute11 = Math.floor(sekunde11 / 60);
    var sati11 = Math.floor(minute11 / 60);
    var dani11 = Math.floor(sati11 / 24);
    sati11 %= 24;
    minute11 %= 60;
    sekunde11 %= 60;

    $("#dani11Box").html(dani11);
    $("#sati11Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati11 + ':');
    $("#minute11Box").html(minute11 + ':');
    $("#sekunde11Box").html(sekunde11);

    timer11 = setTimeout(cdtd11, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd11();
});

var timer12;
function cdtd12() {
    var sad12 = new Date();
    var dolazak12 = new Date(sad12.getFullYear(),sad12.getMonth(),sad12.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff12 = dolazak12.getTime() - sad12.getTime();
    if (timeDiff12 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer12);
        $("#Box12").remove();

    }
    var sekunde12 = Math.floor(timeDiff12 / 1000);
    var minute12 = Math.floor(sekunde12 / 60);
    var sati12 = Math.floor(minute12 / 60);
    var dani12 = Math.floor(sati12 / 24);
    sati12 %= 24;
    minute12 %= 60;
    sekunde12 %= 60;

    $("#dani12Box").html(dani12);
    $("#sati12Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati12 + ':');
    $("#minute12Box").html(minute12 + ':');
    $("#sekunde12Box").html(sekunde12);

    timer12 = setTimeout(cdtd12, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd12();
});

var timer13;
function cdtd13() {
    var sad13 = new Date();
    var dolazak13 = new Date(sad13.getFullYear(),sad13.getMonth(),sad13.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff13 = dolazak13.getTime() - sad13.getTime();
    if (timeDiff13 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer13);
        $("#Box13").remove();

    }
    var sekunde13 = Math.floor(timeDiff13 / 1000);
    var minute13 = Math.floor(sekunde13 / 60);
    var sati13 = Math.floor(minute13 / 60);
    var dani13 = Math.floor(sati13 / 24);
    sati13 %= 24;
    minute13 %= 60;
    sekunde13 %= 60;

    $("#dani13Box").html(dani13);
    $("#sati13Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati13 + ':');
    $("#minute13Box").html(minute13 + ':');
    $("#sekunde13Box").html(sekunde13);

    timer13 = setTimeout(cdtd13, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd13();
});

var timer14;
function cdtd14() {
    var sad14 = new Date();
    var dolazak14 = new Date(sad14.getFullYear(),sad14.getMonth(),sad14.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff14 = dolazak14.getTime() - sad14.getTime();
    if (timeDiff14 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer14);
        $("#Box14").remove();

    }
    var sekunde14 = Math.floor(timeDiff14 / 1000);
    var minute14 = Math.floor(sekunde14 / 60);
    var sati14 = Math.floor(minute14 / 60);
    var dani14 = Math.floor(sati14 / 24);
    sati14 %= 24;
    minute14 %= 60;
    sekunde14 %= 60;

    $("#dani14Box").html(dani14);
    $("#sati14Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati14 + ':');
    $("#minute14Box").html(minute14 + ':');
    $("#sekunde14Box").html(sekunde14);

    timer14 = setTimeout(cdtd14, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd14();
});

var timer15;
function cdtd15() {
    var sad15 = new Date();
    var dolazak15 = new Date(sad15.getFullYear(),sad15.getMonth(),sad15.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff15 = dolazak15.getTime() - sad15.getTime();
    if (timeDiff15 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer15);
        $("#Box15").remove();

    }
    var sekunde15 = Math.floor(timeDiff15 / 1000);
    var minute15 = Math.floor(sekunde15 / 60);
    var sati15 = Math.floor(minute15 / 60);
    var dani15 = Math.floor(sati15 / 24);
    sati15 %= 24;
    minute15 %= 60;
    sekunde15 %= 60;

    $("#dani15Box").html(dani15);
    $("#sati15Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati15 + ':');
    $("#minute15Box").html(minute15 + ':');
    $("#sekunde15Box").html(sekunde15);

    timer15 = setTimeout(cdtd15, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd15();
});

var timer16;
function cdtd16() {
    var sad16 = new Date();
    var dolazak16 = new Date(sad16.getFullYear(),sad16.getMonth(),sad16.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff16 = dolazak16.getTime() - sad16.getTime();
    if (timeDiff16 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer16);
        $("#Box16").remove();

    }
    var sekunde16 = Math.floor(timeDiff16 / 1000);
    var minute16 = Math.floor(sekunde16 / 60);
    var sati16 = Math.floor(minute16 / 60);
    var dani16 = Math.floor(sati16 / 24);
    sati16 %= 24;


minute16 %= 60;
    sekunde16 %= 60;

    $("#dani16Box").html(dani16);
    $("#sati16Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati16 + ':');
    $("#minute16Box").html(minute16 + ':');
    $("#sekunde16Box").html(sekunde16);

    timer16 = setTimeout(cdtd16, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd16();
});

var timer17;
function cdtd17() {
    var sad17 = new Date();
    var dolazak17 = new Date(sad17.getFullYear(),sad17.getMonth(),sad17.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff17 = dolazak17.getTime() - sad17.getTime();
    if (timeDiff17 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer17);
        $("#Box17").remove();

    }
    var sekunde17 = Math.floor(timeDiff17 / 1000);
    var minute17 = Math.floor(sekunde17 / 60);
    var sati17 = Math.floor(minute17 / 60);
    var dani17 = Math.floor(sati17 / 24);
    sati17 %= 24;
    minute17 %= 60;
    sekunde17 %= 60;

    $("#dani17Box").html(dani17);
    $("#sati17Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati17 + ':');
    $("#minute17Box").html(minute17 + ':');
    $("#sekunde17Box").html(sekunde17);

    timer17 = setTimeout(cdtd17, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd17();
});



var timer18;
function cdtd18() {
    var sad18 = new Date();
    var dolazak18 = new Date(sad18.getFullYear(),sad18.getMonth(),sad18.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff18 = dolazak18.getTime() - sad18.getTime();
    if (timeDiff18 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer18);
        $("#Box18").remove();

    }
    var sekunde18 = Math.floor(timeDiff18 / 1000);
    var minute18 = Math.floor(sekunde18 / 60);
    var sati18 = Math.floor(minute18 / 60);
    var dani18 = Math.floor(sati18 / 24);
    sati18 %= 24;
    minute18 %= 60;
    sekunde18 %= 60;

    $("#dani18Box").html(dani18);
    $("#sati18Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati18 + ':');
    $("#minute18Box").html(minute18 + ':');
    $("#sekunde18Box").html(sekunde18);

    timer18 = setTimeout(cdtd18, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd18();
});

var timer19;
function cdtd19() {
    var sad19 = new Date();
    var dolazak19 = new Date(sad19.getFullYear(),sad19.getMonth(),sad19.getDate(),18,00,00);
    var timeDiff19 = dolazak19.getTime() - sad19.getTime();
    if (timeDiff19 <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer19);
        $("#Box19").remove();

    }
    var sekunde19 = Math.floor(timeDiff19 / 1000);
    var minute19 = Math.floor(sekunde19 / 60);
    var sati19 = Math.floor(minute19 / 60);
    var dani19 = Math.floor(sati19 / 24);
    sati19 %= 24;
    minute19 %= 60;
    sekunde19 %= 60;

    $("#dani19Box").html(dani19);
    $("#sati19Box").html('7-Dubrava ' + sati19 + ':');
    $("#minute19Box").html(minute19 + ':');
    $("#sekunde19Box").html(sekunde19);

    timer19 = setTimeout(cdtd19, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     cdtd19();
});



//}
</script>           

<center>
<h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:2px;">&nbsp;</h1>

    <div id="Box1">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati1Box"></div>
    <div id="minute1Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde1Box"></div>
    </div>



    <div id="Box2">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati2Box"></div>
    <div id="minute2Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde2Box"></div>
    </div>



    <div id="Box3">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati3Box"></div>
    <div id="minute3Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde3Box"></div>
    </div>



    <div id="Box4">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati4Box"></div>
    <div id="minute4Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde4Box"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="Box5">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati5Box"></div>
    <div id="minute5Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde5Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box6">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati6Box"></div>
    <div id="minute6Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde6Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box7">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati7Box"></div>
    <div id="minute7Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde7Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box8">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati8Box"></div>
    <div id="minute8Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde8Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box9">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati9Box"></div>
    <div id="minute9Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde9Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box10">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati10Box"></div>
    <div id="minute10Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde10Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box11">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati11Box"></div>
    <div id="minute11Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde11Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box12">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati12Box"></div>
    <div id="minute12Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde12Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box13">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati13Box"></div>
    <div id="minute13Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde13Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box14">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati14Box"></div>
    <div id="minute14Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde14Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box15">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati15Box"></div>
    <div id="minute15Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde15Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box16">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati16Box"></div>
    <div id="minute16Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde16Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box17">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati17Box"></div>
    <div id="minute17Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde17Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box18">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati18Box"></div>
    <div id="minute18Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde18Box"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="Box19">
    <h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>
    <div id="sati19Box"></div>
    <div id="minute19Box"></div>
    <div id="sekunde19Box"></div>
    </div>



<h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:2px;">&nbsp;</h1>
   </center>    

</div>
</body>
</html>

                                                                                                      Thanks
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Until now I don't get it.

Comment: still don't get it :D

Comment: If you open this code there will be 19 contdowns displaying on page, and that's ok. Every countdown is formated in one div(Box1,2,3,..) and in that box there are 3 more divs(sati1Box,minute1Box,sekunde1Box|sati2Box,minute2Box,sekunde2Box...). The Box div exists only to remove all 3 divs and space(<h1 style="font-family:Helvetica;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:5px;">&nbsp;</h1>) at once [$("#Box19").remove();]. How can I make that thare are max 10 countdowns on page. 10 countdown = 40 divs
Now do you get it? :D

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand what you need to do, but you can always watch the number of DIVs on page with

```
var divCount = document.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either set `display:none` on the divs you don't want to display, or in jQuery `$('#element').hide();`